# Why are offsets not reset to 0 after recreating consumer group with the same groupId

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

For example. Here is a consumer group with offsets of 100,and groupId is 'group-0'.
I use kafka-consumer-groups to delete that consumer group.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <address> --delete --group group-0 --execute
```

And it returned success:

```
Deletion of requested consumer group ('group-0') was successful.
```

Then I recreated the group with the same id 'group-0'.
why the new group still hold offsets 100? why not 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Kafka stores the offsets for each Consumer Groups within an internal Kafka topic *__consumer_offsets* for which the retention policy is set to `compact`. That means it takes some time for the internal log cleaner to actually remove that information for your Consumer Group.

You could either wait that configurable amount of time, or, if you just want to re-set the offset from 100 to 0 it is usually better to do this with

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
 --execute --reset-offsets \
 --group group-0 \
 --topic topicName \
 --partition 0 \
 --to-offset 0
```